# Disable auto numbering list when inserting paragraph

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have word document with numbered list.

1. Static text 1.
2. **Bookmarked item.**
3. Static text 3.

One of those items is bookmarked and I need to replace the bookmark with text that consists of several paragraphs.

When I replace the bookmarked item with text that consists of several paragraphs I get autonumerated items for each paragraph added:

```
bookmark1.Range.Text = "Replaced P1."+Environment.NewLine
                      +"Replaced P2."+Environment.NewLine
```

1. Static text 1.
2. **Replaced P1.**
3. **Replaced P2.**
4. Static text 3.

How can I skip autonumerating and add all text to single list item?

**UPD:**
Also numbered list style have left align, and each inserted paragraph must have the same left align.

Like this:

__*1. Static text 1. more text

more text

_*_2. **Replaced P1.**
__**Replaced P2. more text

more text**

__3. Static text 3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer in [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/worddev/thread/60315605-717c-4397-84d5-96586a8b88e7), the key here is to use the `\v` escape character for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> key-combination (inserts a vertical tab). So, basically, you can do this:

```
// Get bookmark
var bookmark = myDocument.Bookmarks["myBookmark"];

// Get the list item
var listItem = bookmark.Range.ListParagraphs[1];

// Change the text using "Shift+Enter" escaped using "\v"
listItem.Range.Text = "Replacement Line 1\vReplacement Line 2\r";
```

(Tested with success on Word 2013 and version 15 of the Word Interop API)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not actually that I need, because first line in each paragraph must have left align the same as number in list.

Comment: My code produces the same output as the one you describe in the question? Are there other requirements than that I should be aware of?